# How to design a state machine

Tags: state-machine

I was hoping someone could help me design this state machine correctly. I'm using Spring state machine with Papyrus for this project. I have a lot of simple, orthogonal states and one sort of "master" state that depends on all the others being "on." So, let's say...

```
M.off -> M.on
A.off -> A.on
B.off -> B.on
C.off -> C.on
```

There are events that trigger a transition from A.off to A.on, B.off to B.on, etc. I have each of these (A, B, C) in its own region. Only when A B and C are all in the "on" position do I want to transition to the M.on state.

I'm unsure of the best way to structure this in a state machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if M is in "on" and any of A, B, C get an "off" event? Does M go to off again? Or is it a one-way process where once M is on M stays on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the details of Spring Statemachine. But for a UML state machine a solution would be to join when all regions are in their "on" state.

It's not clear from the question what happens when A, B, or C go to off when M is "on". Assumption: M goes to "off".

To make/keep this simple I add an history pseudo-state to each region in order to remember which regions were "on" whenever one goes to "off".

[image: Diagram of state machine]

The transitions to the join will trigger when *all* of the source states of the incoming transitions are active (so only if A && B && C are "on").